# Get Experiment that Created Model in MLflow

Tags: mlflow

I want to get the name of the experiment that contains the run that created a registered MLflow model. How can I do this using MLflow, if I just have the name of the model and the version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andre has said, I had to write my own function to achieve this,

```
def get_model_experiment(model_name, model_version):
    # get run_id of the model version
    run_id = mlflow_client.get_model_version(model_name, model_version).run_id

    # get the experiment_id from the run_id
    experiment_id = mlflow_client.get_run(run_id).info.experiment_id

    # get the experiment name from the experiment_id
    return mlflow_client.get_experiment(experiment_id).name
```

Answer (score 0):

The registered model version has a pointer to the run ID. You can then get the experiment_id from the run, and with this get all the experiment info. Look at the API docs.